# 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Cast'

Tags: c#

I am getting the error:

> 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and no extension method 'Cast' accepting a first argument of type 'string[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

on the following piece of code:

```
return mNames.Cast().ToArray();
```

What using directive or assembly reference do I need?
How do I find out such things?

I'm a noob at C# and .NET, I'm just copying code to get a job done, so don't get too technical with me.

Comment: if mNames is an array why do you try to cast it to an array?

Comment: [`Enumerable.Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx#Y1254) casts the elements of an `IEnumerable` to the **specified** type, but you haven't specified the type.

Comment: string[] mNames = new string[5] { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };

Comment: I don't get why you are casting it? It's in the type that you need anyway?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

(1) Make sure you are working on C# 3.0+

(2) Make sure your code contains:

```
using System.Linq;
```

(3) `.Cast` is a generic method, you need to specify the type parameter, like this:

```
return mNames.Cast<AnotherType>().ToArray();
```

Comment: That's done the trick - thanks - so much for copying code :-)

Comment: @Graham - so what was `AnotherType` in the end?

Comment: AnotherType was object in the end

Answer (score 6):

That usually happens when you're missing `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file.

You'll also need to be using .NET 3.5 or greater for it to work. `System.Linq` is in the assembly System.Core.dll, which is included by default in projects that use .NET 3.5 or higher.

**EDIT**

On closer inspection, that code will never work as written, because the `Enumerable.Cast()` method is generic, and requires you to pass in the type that you are casting to: e.g. `mNames.Cast<object>().ToArray();`

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you call the `Cast<T>()` extension method with a type argument, like `mNames.Cast<SomeType>()`.

Anyway, `mNames` already seems to be a `string[]`, so what do you want to cast it to? 
Casting to `object` wouldn't be necessary, because `object[]` can be assigned from `string[]`.

Comment: May be intending to upcast to object for some reason?

Comment: @BennorMcCarthy No need to. `object[]` is assignable from `string[]`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Not sure what the point would be because I'm struggling to think of anything you can cast a string to using `Enumerable.Cast()` other than object.

Comment: @BennorMcCarthy Usually nothing i guess, since string is sealed. Looks like user defined conversion operators don't change this either.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you don't explicitly use "Cast" this compile error will also come up if you use Linq expressions and forget "using System.Linq;"

Answer (score -1):

use `primary.AddRange(secondary);`